# SQL - Copy rows from table to table w/ modified values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I'm trying to copy multiple rows from table to another as following:

```
DataSet dt2 = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT text,castka FROM zajsluz WHERE akce='" + tentoradek + "' and rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'", spojeni);
SDA2.Fill(dt2);
spojeni.Close();

string sqlcom2 = "INSERT INTO zajsluz(akce,text,castka,rocnik) values (@akce,@text,@castka,@rocnik)";

SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand(sqlcom2, spojeni);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce", zakce.Text);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rocnik", klientClass.Rocnik());
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", dt2.Tables["zajsluz"].Columns["text"]);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@castka", dt2.Tables["zajsluz"].Columns["castka"]);
spojeni.Open();
sc2.ExecuteNonQuery();
spojeni.Close();
```

But I get this:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object** when doing `sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", dt2.Tables["zajsluz"].Columns["text"]);`

Comment: Is you dataset column really named `text`?

Comment: Isn't it ? May I kindly ask where the I made a mistake?

Comment: Hi marek - Can you please tell us more in which line of code are u getting an error.Kindly put a debugger and check the execution flow

Comment: @Marek, change your ÌNSERT` query as in @Gordon answer, then, you don't need `DataSet` anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `insert . . . select` form of `insert`.  The structure would look like:

```
INSERT INTO zajsluz(akce, text, castka, rocnik)
    SELECT @skce, text, castka, @rocnik 
    FROM zajsluz
    WHERE akce='" + tentoradek + "' and rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'"
```

You need to insert the values of the variables to get what you want.

Comment: Also it would be highly recommend to use **parametrized queries** instead of building the SQL statement by concatenating SQL and unvalidated user input directly ...